# Convert body argument to String and convert it back to body argument type

Tags: grails

I need to convert dynamic 'body' argument which we give to create a custom tag to String, manipulate it and convert it back.  So that I can alter the body of the custom tag.  I am using Grails version 2.X

Comment: You're going to need more detail to your question. As it stands right now it doesn't make any sense. How about adding an example (even psudo code) of what you are trying to do and also explaining **why** you are doing this.

Comment: @Joshua  I want to create a custom tag in grails which can manipulate its own body....like converting the body element to upper case

Comment: @JoshuaMoore If i give like <namespace:mytag>content</namespace:mytag> in my gsp,
I should get upper case 'CONTENT' rendered in my html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the `body` of the tag in your tag library like this:

```
class SimpleTagLib {
    def simple = { attrs, body ->
      String bodyString = body()
      out << bodyString.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#taglibs) gives you some good information and examples.